# Get the date when most people were online on my website, using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to find out where in Google Analytics I can see the "peak" of "active users" online on my site.

The realtime report gives me:

[image: google analytics realtime]

In the screenshot it says 368. But where can I find the highest one in the history of my site's tracking? Or how can I retrieve this number?

Comment: Why 3 close flags for "off-topic"? 1. Google Analytics is a web app. 2. I am searching for a way to extract certain data, which is not obvious. Off-topic?

Comment: You'll have better luck getting a good answer at [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the *date* instead of timestamp of peak active users, it's fairly simple. Go to Audience > Overview > Update date range to maximum > Find peak in chart.

Try also this: Go to Query Explorer ([ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer))

Check out my settings:

[image: GA query explorer]

> metrics = ga:users
>   dimensions = ga:dateHourMinute
>   sort = -ga:users (descending)

Comment: This is the daily peak. I am searching for the "real time peak" coming from "Active users right now".

Comment: Try this: go to Query Explorer (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

Check out my settings: https://imgur.com/a/md1iCtw

metrics = ga:users
dimensions = ga:dateHourMinute
sort = -ga:users (descending)

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot. - Please update your answer and add the screenshot, so that I can choose it as best! -- PS: But I think the data is not correct since I have one of the vistor peaks noted down, but it does not show the right "peak" number in the data on that day.

Comment: @KaiNoack Updated answer. Regarding the right "peak," real-time peak is the actual count reported as they occur, which is in the order or seconds. The above method presents the data in the order of minutes. I think this is probably the closest we can get. As a sanity check, the above method should report data higher than any of your noted visitor peaks.